# Can method return a Layout

Tags: java, swing, layout, methods, layout-manager

I want a Java method to return the layout of a component. Is it possible in Java?

For example,

```
returntype myMethod()
{
  return panel.getLayout();
}
```

Comment: Why not? Layout is just another type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
LayoutManager getLayout(Container c) {
    return c.getLayout();
}
```

See the [`java.awt.Container`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html) class for reference.

Answer (score 2):

You could do

```
public LayoutManager getPanelLayout() {
  return panel.getLayout();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible with the return type [LayoutManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/LayoutManager.html)